# Call a sub from by double clicking a specific cell (say ("O1"))

Tags: excel, vba

Provide the code for Calling  a sub from by double clicking a specific cell (say ("O1")).

Here is my code , its not working:-

```
Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, _
                                        Cancel As Boolean)

If Intersect(target, Range("O1")) Is Nothing Then

 Else
   Call OpenSupport2Tool
End If
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(target, Range("O1")) Is Nothing Then
   Call OpenSupport2Tool
   Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```